# How to use function pointers to call member functions from its memory address?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, inline-assembly

I'm developing a patch to an old application which the owners doesn't have the src code anymore.

I'm injecting a dll into the target application's .exe before its main(). This dll install the patches I did.

The application have a C++ custom type (class or struct) of what seems to be a drawing font manager which have functions that I need to call through some of these patches.

The way I usually call these "native" member functions is creating a wrapper function that calls the native member function through asm inline. I do this way because I can't find out how to accomplish this through C++ function pointers.

I'm trying again to accomplish this in a better way than creating a lot of bloated function wrappers. This time I'm trying to use a class/struct as a virtual wrapper of that native type, but it seems I'm missing something related to function pointer syntax that I can't figure out.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
/* NC for Native Class */
class NC_FontDevice
{
public:
    typedef void(NC_FontDevice::*_UseTexturesTransparency)();

    _UseTexturesTransparency *UseTexturesTransparency = reinterpret_cast<_UseTexturesTransparency*>(0x635FD0);

private:
    NC_FontDevice(){}
};

NC_FontDevice* GetFontDevice()
{
    NC_FontDevice* lpFontDevice = nullptr;

    /* 
        This asm inline block is here to show more or less what I do in those wrappers I told.
        I know this can be converted to a simple function pointer.
    */
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 0x0041FE10
        call eax
        mov lpFontDevice, eax
    }

    return lpFontDevice;
}

void foo()
{
    auto lpFontDevice = GetFontDevice();

    // Here I get and "identifier X is undefined"
    (lpFontDevice->**UseTexturesTransparency)();
}
```

In case it is clear what I want, is there a better way to accomplish it besides that function wrappers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. One tricky thing here is that the solution will depend a lot on whether these member functions are virtual or not.

Comment: @Frank I can see that problem. However in this particular case the member functions I need to work with are not virtual.

Comment: `UseTexturesTransparency` is a pointer to a function pointer. You need to remove a layer of indirection, and then fool the compiler into assigning the address to the correct value, which will most likely involve memcpying the address in the pointer. Something roughly like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UNo3a_)

Comment: Hmm I see. Interesting solution, I'll dig into it later. I was hoping some native support of the compiler here though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your problems is at least that your code doesn't match your question. You talk about function pointers, yet you write `void(NC_FontDevice::*_UseTexturesTransparency)()`. That is **not** a function pointer. That is a pointer to member function (PMF). Entirely different beasts, and you can't assume these are simple pointers. They're generally not even the same size.

I suspect that you've found a function at `0x635FD0`. That function probably looks like `void _UseTexturesTransparency(NC_FontDevice*)`. Sure, it might have been (part of) a member function when it was compiled, but that doesn't really matter. This is hacking, we're being pragmatic here. Why deal with the complexities of a PMF if we can treat this as an ordinary function pointer?

[edit]
Per the comments, MSVC++ will have used `ECX` for the `this` argument in member functions; as it happens it also supports the `__fastcall` calling convention for regular functions which puts the first 32 bit argument in `ECX`. It's not a perfect replacement; `__fastcall` also uses EDX for its second argument. You might need a dummy argument there, if the existing code expects further arguments on the stack.

You can check for stack arguments because under the `__thiscall` calling convention for member functions, the callee cleans the stack. Luckily this matches the `__fastcall` convention.

Comment: Hmm I confess I did not know what I did in the example was a "pointer to member function". Will definitely take a time to study it. However about the suggestion you made of using an ordinary function pointer, may you explain how I could use an ordinary function pointer as I need the compiler to add the code for passing the "this pointer" in ECX before calling the function? I have no idea how to do that with an ordinary function pointer.

Comment: @underthevoid: Good point about ECX. Function pointers adhere to calling conventions, and [`__fastcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx) happens to put its first DWORD-sized argument in ECX (assuming x86 here, on x64 it wouldn't matter as it always uses RCX)

Comment: Very well thought! I'm ready to accept your anwer. Do you mind editing the answer to include this hack using __fastcall? Thanks for the insight!

Comment: EDIT: Just for completeness for future readers you may point out that __fastcall will put the second parameter in EDX too, so the "real" parameters must start in the third one; also there is the fact __fastcall will align the stack in the callee.

Comment: @underthevoid: Added; also the stack bit. (It's more than aligning)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using std::bind and std::function instead ? C++11 and boost have it.

```
    std::function x = std::bind(&ClassName::function,this);
```

This will create a callback function which will work on your object.

Comment: Hi @Pawel and welcome to SO (: I will take a look on this suggestion you made and get back when I have some background of this.